# make js function wait for eventlistener

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try to upload some files. I have to upload every time only one because I run the webserver on a 32b raspberry pi, which has a maximum of 2gb post.

Does anyone know how to make the forloop wait until the every single file is uploaded. I want to upload a ton of files. So if it tries to upload 1000 files at the same time it would most likly crash.
How do I make the file wait until I got a response from the event manager

```
function uploadFiles(){
        var userfiles = _("fileg").files;
        for(var i = 0; i < userfiles.length; i++){
            var formdata = new FormData();
            var file = userfiles[i];
            formdata.append("file", file);
            formdata.append("username", "test");
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "parser.php");
            ajax.send(formdata);
            valu = i + 1;
            _("status2").innerHTML = valu+"/"+userfiles.length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot make a sync function wait for an async operation. This is why promises exist

Comment: instead of doing a for loop, `pop` a file and upload. On your `completeHandler` make it `pop` the next one and upload if there are still files

Comment: @iagowp how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is quite easy to do with a `for` loop and Fetch :

```
const uploadFiles = async () => {
    for (let file of  _("fileg").files) {
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file", file);
        formdata.append("username", "test");

        await fetch('parser.php', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formdata
        });
    }
}
```

Requests will be made one by one, in order.